# Telerik Scheduler Reminder event

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I am using Telerik Scheduler Reminder (winform), i need to catch event that launch the Reminder window when the time i comes, that i can change it to meet my needs.  I looked all over the properties and there is no such event.  Anyone know where is the problem?

My code

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.radScheduler1.Appointments.BeginUpdate();
            DateTime dtStart = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5);//here i ser reminder for 5sec after i lunch the program
            DateTime dtEnd = dtStart.AddHours(1);
            Appointment appointment = new Appointment(dtStart, dtEnd, "One", "This is first");
            appointment.BackgroundId = (int)AppointmentBackground.MustAttend;
            appointment.StatusId = (int)AppointmentStatus.Unavailable;
            appointment.Snoozed = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

            this.radScheduler1.Appointments.Add(appointment);
}
```

Comment: If there is indeed such an event, your going to have to take advantage of it on the client-side.  I never customized that UI, but I have customized the insert/edit template, and from my experience, it required getting into the low-level JavaScript API to manually customize that interface.  It wasn't pretty.  I have nowhere to point you to, but I'd first look at the client API to see if there is an easy way, and if not, start reading the JS class wrapper.

Comment: it is winform application.

Comment: OK, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

The event that you are looking for is called **AlarmFormShowing**. More information about this is available at the [Telerik UI for WinForms documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/scheduler-reminders-radreminder.html).